# Unable to set contact image in iOS8 using social framework

Tags: ios, ios8, social-networking, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my application i need to set an image as a contact image for a specific contact. For that i have implemented `UIActivityViewController` and it works fine in `iOS7` devices. But in `iOS8` device  while selecting a contact for assigning an image, it is not displaying any options. Am i miss anything special for `iOS8` devices ?

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self, imageUrl] applicationActivities:nil];
//imageUrl - is the NSURL instance for image.
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint];
activityVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
     //Added completion handler    
};
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And it displays `ActivityViewController` as below and on selecting it displays contact list. But the option is not available.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The only thing standing out to me is the activity items you're passing into the controller. Try instantiating it like so:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[image] applicationActivities:nil];
```

This is assuming `image` is a `UIImage`.

Reference: [UIActivityViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivityViewController/initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:)

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for the reply and sorry for the late response.
I changed the code like the way you suggested. However it doesn't solve the problem. The issue is still persist.

Comment: Hmm, I'll check what I'm doing in one of my apps when I get home (I've got an app that does something similar). The other thing that pops into my head is that `imageUrl` might be nil?

Comment: Ah, looks like I'm passing in the `UIImage` itself, rather than a URL to the image. That will likely fix your issue.